# How do I solve the Missing Paranthesis error

Tags: sql, oracle, computer-science, information-schema

I'm trying to a create table command to create a relation;

```
create table Driver(

Driver_Licence char(15) primary key,

SSN int unique,

First_Name varchar(50) not null,

Last_Name varchar(50),

Birth_Date date DEFAULT '1900-01-01',

Hire_Date date COMMENT 'Hire_Date is the date that employee was first Hired',

State char(2),

INDEX (State),

CONSTRAINT CHK_Driver_HireDate CHECK(Hire_Date > Birth_Date)

);
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I've been trying to figure it out, but I've been having trouble figuring out how to solve it. It would be a great help if one of you could help me!

Comment: On other observation, unrelated to your problem.  You have defined SSN as INT.  You should not define columns as numeric types unless they are actually _numbers_.  SSNs, telephone numbers, zip codes are not numbers, they are simply values that are - by an arbitrary rule - limited to numeric _characters_.  If you declare them as number (NUMBER, INT, etc) you risk losing any leading zeros.  BTW, the reason telephone 'dials' have letters associated was not to facilitate text messages, but because telephone numbers originally included alpha.  My first telephone 'number' was WH9-3187.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Oracle supports either inline comments in tables or the creation of indexes.  These need to be separate statements.

Oracle recommends using `varchar2()` instead of `varchar()`.  And the date literal should be preceded with `date`:

```
create table Driver(
    Driver_Licence char(15) primary key,
    SSN int unique,
    First_Name varchar2(50) not null,
    Last_Name varchar2(50),
    Birth_Date date DEFAULT date '1900-01-01',
    Hire_Date date,
    State char(2),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Driver_HireDate CHECK(Hire_Date > Birth_Date)
);

comment on column driver.hire_date is 'Hire_Date is the date that employee was first Hired';

create index idx_driver_state on driver(state);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1644cdc27ae4471d3e5786ef24791d7e) is a db<>fiddle.